# how to allow Java System library to access a variable defined in .zprofile?

Tags: java, macos, getenv

So I am trying to use spring tools along with maven to develop java applications on a mac system using zsh. Invoking System.getenv(var_name) returns null, it is clear to me that System library can't access variable defined in .zprofile on my mac, is there any way I canget this accomplished? thank you

Comment: There are ways to do this, but I'd consider them ugly hacks. .zprofile is run by (some) instances of zsh as they start up, so variables assigned in it are available in zsh itself, and if they're exported in subprocesses as well. But applications don't (normally) run as subprocesses to a shell; zsh isn't involved at all in the normal process of starting an app in macOS. Does the definition *need* to be in .zprofile, rather than in something like a normal preferences file?